# single cell read only in excel using java

Tags: java, excel

How can I make read only cell in Excel using Java ?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate, are you using Apache POI? JExcelApi? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) to achieve this. Here is a simple code sample:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test");

Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setLocked(true);
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellStyle(style);

// this is important as locking is pnly activated if sheet is protected
sheet.protectSheet("");
```

Comment: in the above code 
"cell = row.createCell(0);"
here what is cell

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try [jExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). It is quite simple and easy to use.

Comment: i ve already half completed my work in apache poi so help me to solve this problem with that

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project, specifically the [HSSF & XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) subprojects, that provides a Java library to manipulate Excel documents.